# http post request in Carte web service Kettle

Tags: php, post, get, pentaho, kettle

I want to call a transformation kettle in my php script using carte web service,
the url of this call is : http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/kettle/executeTrans?trans=nameTrans.ktr&param1=value
so by this call i am using get http request,I am asking if there is a way to do the same call by http post request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: but it is possible to send parameters in post with carte pentaho,??the link you mention refers to http post in general .